# How can I access to my previous account?

Tags: support

I have an account in Stack Exchange communities. I use OpenID login, but apparently I can't do this any more. I add Google address as they asked, but it creates this new account and I lose all my previous work.

So, how can I access to my previous account?

Comment: According to that post: "*If you have any problems in this transition or can't successfully add a new provider to your account, please contact us and we'll get it sorted out for you.*"